# How to call soft key board and take user input on click event

Tags: android

I have a view which I have set a click listener on.

```
view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED,0);
            }
        });
```

On clicking the view, a the soft key board will appear.

How can I take input from this keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

Good question, never though about this. The only way I can think is having a hidden `TextView` that will request focus and latter you could read its value.

```
view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                myTextView.requestFocus();
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED,0);
            }
});

...

String textTyped = myTextView.getText().toString();
```